# No such module 'React' - Integrating React Native into existing apps

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, cocoapods, xcode11.4

I'm trying to add React Native into an existing iOS app developed in Swift.

I created a new Swift project and followed the instructions at the [official documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps):

At the "Code Integration" step of this documentation, when I try to "import React" it gives me the following error:

[image]

I can "Jump to Definition":

[image]

Everything is installed either via `yarn` or `pods`.

Tech stack versions are:

```
MacOS: 10.15.4
Xcode: 11.4
React-Native: 0.62.2
React: 16.11.0
RN Cli: 4.8.0
```

I've been looking around for an answer but couldn't find anything related to this. I'm new to React-Native and I've just started to learn Xcode and its underlying principles. So it is possible that I'm missing something very fundamental here. Yet I couldn't figured it out.

Could you point me in the right direction?